# Is the operator $r^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ Lorentz invariant?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, lorentz-symmetry

I've noticed that if you apply the operator $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ to a function that is Lorentz invariant the result is Lorentz invariant. Specifically,
\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f(\tau)}{\partial r} & = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial f(\tau)}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial r} \\
& = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial f(\tau)}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial \sqrt{t^2-r^2}}{\partial r} \\
& = \frac{1}{r} \left(-\frac{r}{\tau}\right)\frac{\partial f(\tau)}{\partial \tau} \\
& = -\frac{1}{\tau} \frac{\partial f(\tau)}{\partial \tau}.
\end{align}

The last line is, clearly, Lorentz invariant. It doesn't seem to be sufficient to show that $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ is Lorentz invariant in general, though. For instance, if we make consider a (not not necessarily invariant) function of both boost, $\phi$, and $\tau$, we get:
\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f(\tau, \phi)}{\partial r} &= \frac{1}{r} \left[\frac{\partial f(\tau, \phi)}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial f(\tau, \phi)}{\partial \phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\right] \\
    & = \frac{1}{r} \left[-\frac{r}{\tau}\frac{\partial f(\tau, \phi)}{\partial \tau} + \frac{\partial f(\tau, \phi)}{\partial \phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\right].
\end{align}
Now, the relations that get from $(\tau,\phi)$ to $(r, t)$  when $t>r>0$ are
\begin{align}
    r &= \tau\sinh\phi, \\
    t &= \tau\cosh\phi.
\end{align}
Going the other direction:
\begin{align}
    \tau & = \sqrt{t^2 - r^2}, \\
    \phi & = \tanh^{-1} \left(\frac{t}{r}\right).
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f(\tau, \phi)}{\partial r} & = -\frac{1}{\tau}\frac{\partial f(\tau, \phi)}{\partial \tau} + \frac{\tanh\phi}{\tau^2}\frac{\partial f(\tau, \phi)}{\partial \phi}.
\end{align}

That expression does not look like the operator is Lorentz invariant, since at least some Lorentz boosts are shifts in $\phi$.

Bottom line, is this an operator that is Lorentz invariant when acting on Lorentz invariant functions, only, or is it more generally invariant than the last equation above suggests? If the former, how can a non-invariant operator leave invariant functions invariant?

Comment: There are no first-order and Lorentz-scalar differential operators (when acting on scalars). The best you can do is to use a second-order one: the Laplacian. The latter is essentially unique.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Really? It seems that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau'}$ with $\tau' \equiv \mathrm{sgn}(t^2-r^2) \sqrt{|t^2-r^2|}$ would qualify.

Comment: Did you, perhaps, mean that there's no [Poincaré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group) invariant first order differential operator, @AccidentalFourierTransform? Because there, I'd agree. Just requiring rotations and boosts about a particular point/event, though, is all I'm interested in.